# SublimeLinter with C++11

Tags: c++11, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I've started using Sublime Text 3 as my code editor for C++ and I installed some additional packages, two of which being SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-contrib-clang. Everything seems to be working fine, except that it looks like there is no support for C++11 in the linter.

[image]

Do you know how I could change that to work with C++11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody with the same problem:

The solution is to go to Preferences -> Package Settings -> SulbimeLinter -> Settings Default.

There you need to paste the following:

```
    "linters":
    {
        "clang": {
            "extra_flags": "-std=c++11"
        }
    },
```

somewhere in the "default" namespace. At least that worked for me.

Cheers!

Comment: I pasted the exact same thing but it did not fix it for me.

Comment: Found the problem. The node for options is 'args' and not 'extra_flags', at least that's what worked for me in version 3.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SublimeLinter-contrib-clang troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/nirm03/SublimeLinter-clang#troubleshooting), it can sometimes has issues finding the C++ standard library headers (see bullet 3). If that doesn't work or if you are not stuck using SublimeLinter-contrib-clang, consider using [SublimeLinter-cpplint](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-cpplint) or [SublimeLinter-cppcheck](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-cppcheck) instead, as these are meant for C++11 development.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is trying it for Sublime Version 3 and other answers are not helping; following worked for me.

It is also mentioned on the home site: https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-clang

```
{
    "linters":
    { 
      "clang++": {
            "args": "-Wall -fsyntax-only -fno-caret-diagnostics -std=c++11",
       },
       "clang": {
            "args": "-Wall -fsyntax-only -fno-caret-diagnostics -std=c++11",
        }
    }
}
```