# Default C++ version SublimeLinter

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I am using `SublimeLinter-clang` with `Sublime 3` to lint `C++` code on MacOS Mojave. I am getting warnings and errors for code from later versions of `C++`. How do I set the default linting version to `C++17`?

For instance, I have the line:

```cpp
auto game = SpinOut{};
```

and the editor marks the following:

- `1 warning: clang++ - 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]`
- `clang++: error - expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`

I tried following the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42818098/6819862) but nothing changed. Below is my `SublimeLinter.sublime.settings`, and I still get the same error and warning.

[image: Settings]

Comment: As I mentioned in my original question, I followed the instructions from that solution and nothing happened. The error still appears. I have attached a screenshot of my `SublimeLinter.sublime.settings`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SublimeLinter-clang is now maintained at https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-clang rather than https://github.com/nirm03/SublimeLinter-clang.

In the newer version there was a pull request in 2018 that added support that gives users the ability to have different settings for the c linter and c++ linter. So the answer from 2017 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42818098/17034 is currently outdated.

So it looks like you will need to change clang to clang++. It also looks like they changed extra_flags to args in the settings, so you will need to override the default args and add -std=c++11.

```
"linters":
{
    "clang++": {
        "args": "-Wall -fsyntax-only -fno-caret-diagnostics -std=c++11"
    }
},
```

Comment: Tried this out and unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Looks like they also changed extra_flags to args. Can you try that as well?